# Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute could not be converted to string

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, error, php-7, mage-googleshopping

I haven't had any problems but I moved to a new server and really haven't check it out for a while but now when I try to add a product to google shopping I get the following error:

```
Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute could not be converted to string in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/community/BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/GoogleProductCategory.php on line 30
```

Here is the code the error is pointing to:

```
    public function convertAttribute($product, $shoppingProduct)
    {   
        // get category from product attribute
  -- line 30 here -->   Mage::log(__LINE__.$product->getResource()->getAttribute('google_shopping_category'));
        $value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('google_shopping_category')
        ->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        $value = preg_replace('/\d+ /','',$value);
        $shoppingProduct->setGoogleProductCategory($value);

        return $shoppingProduct;
    }
```

I've tried many things (mostly guesses) searched on Google and still can't seem to fix this error. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$product->getResource()->getAttribute('google_shopping_category')` returns an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute` and when you are doing this `__LINE__.$product->getResource()->getAttribute('google_shopping_category')` PHP tries to automatically convert the instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute` to a string and it cannot do that.
An alternative would be to replace that with

```
$id = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('google_shopping_category')->getId();
Mage::log(__LINE__.$id);
```

Or, of you need full details of the attribute you can try.

```
$attributeAsString = print_r($product->getResource()->getAttribute('google_shopping_category'), true);
Mage::log(__LINE__.$attributeAsString);
```

Comment: I think that fixed the problem but I ran into another problem but that error is gone. Let me see...

Comment: That got it! Thanks. I had another little problem with one of my attributes not being Google correct.